# Is it possible to only convert the letters and not also the numbers

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to only convert the letters after 4 numbers. With not converting the numbers also. I use `charCodeAt` to do this.

What I want to do is only converting letters and not the numbers. Below I also convert the numbers. I want to convert things after the first 4 characters, the letters are converted to ascii numbers.

```js
function convertZipcodeToInteger(letters){
  letters = letters;
  for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
    let number = letters.charCodeAt(i) % 65 + "";
      if (number.length < 2)
      {
        number = "0" + number;
      }
      console.log(number);
  }
}   convertZipcodeToInteger('7711AD');
```

What I am doing right now with the code is putting `7711AD` into the letters parameter. Putting them through an for loop, so it converts all the letters(and numbers) with `charCodeAt`. When the `number.length` is smaller then 2 it gets a 0 in front of it.

What I want to do is convert it to this: `77110003` this is with the converted letters. I don't want the numbers converted, because they don't need to change.

Comment: you can try regExp

Comment: please add the wanted result and what does not work.

Comment: *converts all the letters(and numbers)* eh? Converts to what? It really does sound like a use case for regex but it really is not clear what you want to do here

Comment: So you want 7711AD to 0004? I fail to see the usefulness of that.

Comment: So if someone enters `7711AD` you want the integer `7711`?

Comment: if someone enters 7711AD, I would like it to be like this: `77110003`

Comment: Is it only after 4 characters, or is it like anytime a number occurs in the text it shouldn't be replaced?

Comment: @MissesA, what are the rules? Why is `AD` should be converted to `0003`?

Comment: The alphabet has 26 letters  and in this case 25 because we begin with counting at zero.  So A will be 0 and D will be 3.

Comment: That seems a slightly bizarre system. A == 00? Why on earth would you want to do that? If you want to encode char characters into integers it'd make much more sense to use the hex code or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test if the value is a number and if not take the letter and convert it to a numerical value based 36 and pad it before returning.

```js
function convertZipcodeToInteger(string) {
    function pad2(s) { return ('00' + s.toString()).slice(-2); }
    
    return string
        .split('')
        .map(function (c) {
            return /\d/.test(c)
                ? c
                : pad2(parseInt(c, 36) - 10);
         })
        .join('')
};

function convertZipcodeToLetter(string) {
    return string.slice(0, 4) + string
        .slice(4)
        .split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/)
        .map(function (s) { return (+s + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase(); })
        .join('');
}

console.log(convertZipcodeToInteger('7711AD'));
console.log(convertZipcodeToLetter('77110003'));
```

Comment: That is it!! Thanks again :)

Comment: Is it also possible that later it can be reversed back to `7711AD`?

Comment: not without some rules, for example that only the first four values are numbers or so.

Comment: The first four are always numbers, the last two out of the six are always letters unless they are converted ofcourse.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to only convert the letters after 4 numbers.

Simply start your **for-loop** from `4`

```
for(var i = 4; i < letters.length; i++){ //notice var i = 4
```

**Edit**

Looks like you want to replace letters every time they occur, not necessarily after 4 numbers,

```
"7711AD".replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(match){ return ( "0" + match.charCodeAt( 0 ) % 65).slice( -2 ) });
```

**Demo**

```js
"7711AD".replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(match) {
  return ( "0" + match.charCodeAt(0) % 65).slice( -2 ); //ensuring that single digit is padded with 0
});
```

Comment: A regex would be a **much** better way to do this.If this is what's getting asked. Which I'm not clear if it is

Comment: @Liam I don't think so. I think regex for this simple task will be an overkill!

Comment: Really, better than finding the modulus of the char code? `letters.charCodeAt(i) % 65`

Comment: @Liam I misunderstood OP's question. Looks like letters should be replaced anywhere they occur rather than only after 4 numbers. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand but this is what I think you are after:
it can also be done without the function with just regexp magic

> **first 4** charaters are **numbers** and should only have 0 added (eg 07)
>   then **2 letters** which should be encoded from 0-26 and always be two charaters long

```js
function convertZipcodeToInteger(letters){
  for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
    let number = letters[i];
    if (i>3) { number = letters.charCodeAt(i) % 65 + ""; }
    if (number.length < 2) {
      number = "0" + number;
    }
    console.log(number);
  }
}   convertZipcodeToInteger('7711AD');
```